# why is the dynamic texts in flash not aligned in IE6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, internet-explorer, dynamic, text

```
<object class="numimg" width="425px" height="400px" data="numbers.swf"  type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="movie" value="numbers.swf">
<param name="quality" value="high">                     
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
</object>
```

so i was doing a website with a random number generator that was made in flash using as3, it looks great in other browsers but the dynamic texts lost its alignment when i opened in ie6.

does anyone have a solution for this? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No reason for IE6 to alter anything inside flash.

Try embedding the font used in the dynamic text box.

Comment: to be honest, i am still new in as3 and still not famillar in font embedding yet but i'll try it next time. thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

IE6 is dead. move along... [Join the countdown](http://www.ie6countdown.com/)

Comment: well.. bad news.. this is a chinese website. haha

Comment: What does it being chinese have to matter?

Answer (score -1):

i solved my own problem. i just have to change the texts from classic texts to TLF text and it's more compatible in IE6

Comment: Or you could have embedded the font, as I stated in my answer!

Comment: Changing it to TLF is not the answer.

Comment: i am just wondering why tlf is not a good way to do it since in my situation, it worked. i honestly have a lot to learn in as3 so i'm sorry if i sound like an idiot. haha.

Comment: @user1820031 TLF Textfield is bundle of extended features for a textbox. So it makes no sense to use the heavy stuff when the same problem can be solved by standard textbox.